# Python re.split() keep portions of delimiter as part of first string and other as part of second, etc

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a situation where I want to split a long block of text into sentences. I have a working piece of code that splits the string as I would like, however it removes the delimiters (which I knew it would). Now, I want to be able to keep those delimiters as part of the output strings (reallocated appropriately).

My example is this:

```
import re

strings = ['UT Arlington 1st - Berthiaume reached on a fielding error by ss (0-0). O. Salinas fouled out to 1b (2-1 KBB). Q. Rohrbaugh flied out to cf (2-0 BB). B. Cox fouled out to lf (2-2 KBBKF)',
'Southeast Mo. State 1st - EZELL, T. lined out to 2b (2-2 FBBKFFF). HOLST, D. flied out to lf (0-2 FK). GAGAN, T. struck out swinging (1-2 BKKS).',
'UT Arlington 3rd - J. Minjarez hit by pitch (0-0); RJ Williams advanced to second. Berthiaume popped up to 1b (0-2 KF). O. Salinas flied out to cf to right center (2-1 KBB); RJ Williams advanced to third.']

for s in strings:
        header = re.split(r'[ ][-][ ]', s)
        print(header[0])
        text = re.split(r'([a-z][.][ ][A-Z]|[)][.][ ][A-Z])', header[-1])
        print(text)
```

Current output:

```
UT Arlington 1st
['Berthiaume reached on a fielding error by ss (0-0', '). O', '. Salinas fouled out to 1b (2-1 KBB', '). Q', '. Rohrbaugh flied out to cf (2-0 BB', '). B', '. Cox fouled out to lf (2-2 KBBKF)']
Southeast Mo. State 1st
['EZELL, T. lined out to 2b (2-2 FBBKFFF', '). H', 'OLST, D. flied out to lf (0-2 FK', '). G', 'AGAN, T. struck out swinging (1-2 BKKS).']
UT Arlington 3rd
['J. Minjarez hit by pitch (0-0); RJ Williams advanced to secon', 'd. B', 'erthiaume popped up to 1b (0-2 KF', '). O', '. Salinas flied out to cf to right center (2-1 KBB); RJ Williams advanced to third.']
```

My desired output:

```
UT Arlington 1st
['Berthiaume reached on a fielding error by ss (0-0)', 'O. Salinas fouled out to 1b (2-1 KBB)', 'Q. Rohrbaugh flied out to cf (2-0 BB)', 'B. Cox fouled out to lf (2-2 KBBKF)']
Southeast Mo. State 1st
['EZELL, T. lined out to 2b (2-2 FBBKFFF)', 'HOLST, D. flied out to lf (0-2 FK)', 'GAGAN, T. struck out swinging (1-2 BKKS).']
UT Arlington 3rd
['J. Minjarez hit by pitch (0-0); RJ Williams advanced to second', 'Berthiaume popped up to 1b (0-2 KF)', 'O. Salinas flied out to cf to right center (2-1 KBB); RJ Williams advanced to third.']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every sentence ends with the current count of the balls and strikes, you can split on `-` or `.` when the the period has the `)` behind i. Also, the regex checks to see if the last letter before a period is lowercase, and the data following is a space and then an uppercase letter (Denoting end of regular sentence and start of new sentence):

```
import re

strings = ['UT Arlington 1st - Berthiaume reached on a fielding error  by ss (0-0). O. Salinas fouled out to 1b (2-1 KBB). Q. Rohrbaugh flied out to cf (2-0 BB). B. Cox fouled out to lf (2-2 KBBKF)', 'Southeast Mo. State 1st - EZELL, T. lined out to 2b (2-2 FBBKFFF). HOLST, D. flied out to lf (0-2 FK). GAGAN, T. struck out swinging (1-2 BKKS).', 'UT Arlington 3rd - J. Minjarez hit by pitch (0-0); RJ Williams advanced to second. Berthiaume popped up to 1b (0-2 KF). O. Salinas flied out to cf to right center (2-1 KBB); RJ Williams advanced to third.']

new_data = [re.split("(?<!\d)-(?!\d)|(?<=\))\.|(?<=[a-z])\.(?=\s[A-Z])", i) for i in strings]

for plays in new_data:
    print new_data
```

Comment: This is not always true: O. Salinas flied out to cf to right center (2-1 KBB); RJ Williams advanced to third.

Comment: This splits the counts at the end of the strings due to the capital letters denoting pitch sequences. It also will split the heading for Southeast Mo. State, however this could be pre-processed to avoid this result.

Comment: @RickAhlf fixed to avoid splitting at the counts.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using regular expressions, you might want to have a look at [**`nltk`**](http://www.nltk.org/):

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize

strings = ['UT Arlington 1st - Berthiaume reached on a fielding error by ss (0-0). O. Salinas fouled out to 1b (2-1 KBB). Q. Rohrbaugh flied out to cf (2-0 BB). B. Cox fouled out to lf (2-2 KBBKF)',
'Southeast Mo. State 1st - EZELL, T. lined out to 2b (2-2 FBBKFFF). HOLST, D. flied out to lf (0-2 FK). GAGAN, T. struck out swinging (1-2 BKKS).',
'UT Arlington 3rd - J. Minjarez hit by pitch (0-0); RJ Williams advanced to second. Berthiaume popped up to 1b (0-2 KF). O. Salinas flied out to cf to right center (2-1 KBB); RJ Williams advanced to third.']

needle = " - "
for string in strings:
    pos = string.find(needle)
    header = string[:pos]
    text = string[pos + len(needle):]
    print(header)   
    print(sent_tokenize(text))
```

Which yields:

```
UT Arlington 1st
['Berthiaume reached on a fielding error by ss (0-0).', 'O. Salinas fouled out to 1b (2-1 KBB).', 'Q. Rohrbaugh flied out to cf (2-0 BB).', 'B. Cox fouled out to lf (2-2 KBBKF)']
Southeast Mo. State 1st
['EZELL, T. lined out to 2b (2-2 FBBKFFF).', 'HOLST, D. flied out to lf (0-2 FK).', 'GAGAN, T. struck out swinging (1-2 BKKS).']
UT Arlington 3rd
['J. Minjarez hit by pitch (0-0); RJ Williams advanced to second.', 'Berthiaume popped up to 1b (0-2 KF).', 'O. Salinas flied out to cf to right center (2-1 KBB); RJ Williams advanced to third.']
```

The header is extracted via string functions (`.find()`) and the sentences are analyzed afterwards via `sent_tokenize()`.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

### Brief

Ok, so this works for all the use-cases you presented, but by no means is it perfect. The complications arise with periods `.` in the middle of your sentences. This makes it complicated because they are no longer normal sentence terminators, but instead, represent *something else* such as an initial.

### Code

[You can see this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/56uxfI/3)

```
\h*+(.{2,}?(?:\.|$))(?=(?:\h+[A-Z])|$)
```

---

### Results

#### Input 1

```
J. Minjarez hit by pitch (0-0); RJ Williams advanced to second. Berthiaume popped up to 1b (0-2 KF). O. Salinas flied out to cf to right center (2-1 KBB); RJ Williams advanced to third.
```

#### Output 1

```
J. Minjarez hit by pitch (0-0); RJ Williams advanced to second.

Berthiaume popped up to 1b (0-2 KF).

O. Salinas flied out to cf to right center (2-1 KBB); RJ Williams advanced to third.
```

---

#### Input 2

```
EZELL, T. lined out to 2b (2-2 FBBKFFF). HOLST, D. flied out to lf (0-2 FK). GAGAN, T. struck out swinging (1-2 BKKS).
```

#### Output 2

```
EZELL, T. lined out to 2b (2-2 FBBKFFF).

HOLST, D. flied out to lf (0-2 FK).
```

GAGAN, T. struck out swinging (1-2 BKKS).

---

#### Input 3

```
Berthiaume reached on a fielding error by ss (0-0). O. Salinas fouled out to 1b (2-1 KBB). Q. Rohrbaugh flied out to cf (2-0 BB). B. Cox fouled out to lf (2-2 KBBKF)
```

#### Output 3

```
Berthiaume reached on a fielding error by ss (0-0).

O. Salinas fouled out to 1b (2-1 KBB).

Q. Rohrbaugh flied out to cf (2-0 BB).
```

---

### Explanation

The regex works as follows:

- Match between zero and unlimited horizontal whitespace `\h` characters as many times as possible without giving back
- Capture between 2 and unlimited of any character (except newline), but as few as possible, followed by a `.` or the end of the string `$`
- Ensure the previous is followed by one of the following

  - One to unlimited horizontal white space characters, followed by a capital letter `[A-Z]`
  - End of the string `$`

The reason I use `.{2,}?` is to specify that we want to match at least 2 characters (initials only have 1 character preceding a `.`, so these will be ignored as being a sentence in the case of e.g. `B. Cox`). It's using a lazy quantifier so that it stops when the next token is matched (a dot `\.` [or the end of the string `$`])

---

## Edit

Since python's `re` module doesn't support possessive quantifiers (and also doesn't seem to support `\h` as horizontal whitespace character according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/), I've slightly edited the regex as shown below.

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/56uxfI/4)

```
\s*(\S.{1,}?(?:\.|$))(?=(?:\s+[A-Z])|$)
```

Comment: @Jan I completely agree, but this is a possibility that *might* work for the OP depending on the usage. I'm not saying this is the best solution, which is why I stated in the first sentence that this answer is *by no means [...] perfect*, but it does allow the OP to do what they are trying while using regex.

Comment: I really appreciate your thorough answer, however it seems that nltk may be the route I want to go for that very reason. And your answer did address the OP.

Comment: @RickAhlf No hard feelings, Jan's answer is likely a much better answer than using regex. Who knows, maybe this answer will help someone else ;)

Comment: I'm sure it will. It also gave me some more insight into regex, so much appreciated!

Comment: @Jan thanks, I've added an edit to my post. This should work for python now. I believe `\h` also doesn't work in python, but can't confirm, I've changed it to `\s` instead

Comment: @Jan I've noticed. PCRE way ahead of it here

Comment: @ctwheels: The outstanding `regex` (`pip install regex`) module aims to fill the gap - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/